# How to switch cameras while recording a video with the camera package

Tags: flutter, camera, instagram

I'm trying to reproduce the instagram application in flutter with firebase. I'm trying to code the camera view as well as the management of a video capture. Everything works correctly for a video taken with the front and rear cameras. But I'd just like to make a video where I switch from the front to the rear camera and vice versa during the same video. Unfortunately, with the camera package I can't do it. Has anyone done this before, and how? An example would be great! Thanks a lot!

I just need it to be able to take a single video despite the switch and then display it to me.